# Magento performance tests

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to understand the test results as I don't fully understand what these numbers means. Can someone please explain what these numbers mean and which result is better? I have results from two different magento stores. Which is better?

[image]

[image]

Comment: these numbers do not mean anything if they can not be compared with the readings on the server. what happens on the server at the time of testing. like: top, htop, mytop, varnishstat, ngxtop

Answer (score 5):

Most of these should be easy to understand for anyone with working technical knowledge of Magento stores, but I'll try to get some definitions in a Magento context for you.

- **Transactions [Higher is better]** : Without seeing your actual tests, I would generalize that this does not necessarily mean Magento checkout transactions, but rather webrequest transactions. All my later descriptions assume you're tracking individual webrequest transactions instead of Magento Checkout transactions.
- **Availability [Higher is better]** : 100% availability means that your store did not timeout or crash during the Siege test. If it drops below 100% that means some web pages were not able to be served to the browser. This is a bad thing.
- **Elapsed time [Just a record]** : Really this doesn't matter as much, it just tells you how long the Siege test ran.
- **Data transferred [Higher is better]** : The more data your server can transfer in a given Elapsed time, the more customers you can server faster.
- **Response time [Lower is better] : This one is *important*. The faster your server responds to requests the better.
- **Transaction Rate [Higher is better]** : This is how many webrequest transactions your server is responding to per second.
- **Throughput [Higher is better]** : Data transferred is directly related to this. All other server related speeds being equal (not the case here) this means your have a faster internet connection on your server.
- **Concurrency [Higher is better]** : The more customers your server can serve pages to concurrently the better, more people can checkout from your store at the same time.
- **Successful transactions [Higher is better]** : This is a count of the amount of webrequest transactions your server responded to during the test.
- **Failed transactions [Lower is better]** : If this is 0 like it is in your tests, then Availability up top will be 100%.
- **Longest Transaction [Lower is better]** : The longer a webrequest is going to take the more frustrated your customer is going to be. If you want to know what are good transaction response times take a look at [YSlow](http://yslow.org/)
- **Shortest Transaction [Lower is better]** : Same as above.

It is important to note that while your tests seem to make the first server look better than the second one there are lots of resources online for making your server faster and also fast webrequest transactions does not guarantee fast Magento checkout transactions. You want to test actual transaction speeds with a more customized test to ensure you are not losing customers during the most important part of making a sale.